# What classes to take to start learning about ARM?

Tags: arm

I want to learn more about the cortex M0, M3 and ARM cores in general and am willing to pay up to 1k for classes.  What are the best ways to spend that?  Best ways for someone interested in consumer electronics (not at the scale of a building a computer, more at the scale of building IoT widgets).

Comment: Decide on a project, buy an evaluation board that has the required peripherals, print the datasheets/user-manuals, start reading, designing and coding, ask on this forum when you run into a specific problem, and keep ~ 0.9k in your pocket.

Comment: For a general insight: Addison Wesley - ARM System-on-Chip Architecture

Comment: For diving into cortex-M; "The Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex-M3" (Joseph Yiu). Also for some microcontrollers Hıtex has some nice quick start guides, for example "The Insider's Guide to the stm32"

Answer (score 2):

You can take this free online embedded course from The University of Texas at Austin: [UT.6.02x Embedded Systems - Shape the World](https://courses.edx.org/courses/UTAustinX/UT.6.02x/1T2015/info).

It's an introductory class into ARM microcontrollers and the C language. The class uses [TM4C123 Tiva LaunchPad board](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-connected-ek-tm4c123gxl.html) from Texas Instruments which is based on an ARM Cortex-M4 microcontroller and it only costs $13!.

Course description:

> This is a hand-on, learn-by-doing course that shows you how to build
>   solutions to real-world problems using embedded systems. Each student
>   will purchase a Texas Instruments TM4C123 microcontroller kit and a
>   few electronic components. This microcontroller has a state of the art
>   ARM Cortex M4 processor. The course uses a bottom-up approach to
>   problem-solving building gradually from simple interfacing of switches
>   and LEDs to complex concepts like display drivers, digital to analog
>   conversion, generation of sound, analog to digital conversion,
>   graphics, interrupts, and communication. We will present both general
>   principles and practical tips for building circuits and programming
>   the microcontroller in the C programming language. You will develop
>   debugging skills using oscilloscopes, logic analyzers and software
>   instrumentation. Laboratory assignments are first performed in
>   simulation, and then you will build and debug your system on the real
>   microcontroller. At the conclusion of this course you will be able to
>   build your own arcade-style game.